# I am trying to upload the image on server after taking snap from phone but after I upload it on server image gets b

Tags: android

I am trying to upload image on server after taking snap from phone but after uploading it on server image gets blur.. How to improvise it.. As we used bitmap for reducing the image quality.. Can anybody suggest me the right way??

```
 // select image from Gallery
        public void selectImageFromGallery() {
            final String[] items = new String[]{"Camera", "Gallery"};
            final Integer[] icons = new Integer[]{R.drawable.ic_camera, R.drawable.ic_gallery};
            ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapterWithIcon(CommentCreationUpdationActivity.this, items, icons);
            new AlertDialog.Builder(CommentCreationUpdationActivity.this).setTitle("Select Picture")
                    .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            if (items[item].equals("Camera")) {
                                if (isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                                } else {
                                    showCustomToast(" No camera on this device !!");
                                }
                            } else if (items[item].equals("Gallery")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);

                            }
                        }
                    }).show();

        }

        private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
            if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                    PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
                // this device has a camera
                return true;
            } else {
                // no camera on this device
                return false;
            }
        }

        // get result after selecting image from Gallery
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
                    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(selectedImage);
                    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];
                    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            filePathColumn, sel, new String[]{id}, null);
                } else {
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                }
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                Constant.picturePathList.add(picturePath);
                Bitmap bitmap1 = decodeFile(picturePath);
                Constant.bitmapList.add(bitmap1);
                cursor.close();
                addImagesInLinearLayout();
            }else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK  && null != data) {
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
                Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);
                // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
                String selectedImagePath =getRealPathFromURI(tempUri);
                Constant.picturePathList.add(selectedImagePath);
                Bitmap bitmap1 = decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                Constant.bitmapList.add(bitmap1);
                addImagesInLinearLayout();
            }

        }
        public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);//I have doubt here
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
            return Uri.parse(path);
        }

        public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(idx);
        }

        public Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath) {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024; //I  have doubt here
            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
            return bitmap;
        }
```

Comment: I'm no sure what is the problem. But you don't have to decode the image into bitmap for send it. In fact you are sending a huge array. Because the image is bigger in memory than in disk. I think a better solution is just read the FILE and send it. Maybe you cand try to store in png format.